# Links to review history on the election page are broken

Tags: bug, status-completed, election, review, profile-page

On the [election page](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election) there is a link "review history" under each nomination. It's supposed to display the list of nominee's reviews, but it does not. The reason is a recent tweak of user profile pages: the tab "activity" has been renamed "all actions" and its URL was changed accordingly. The election page has outdated links.

---

In case this does not get fixed quickly, the functioning links to the reviews of present nominees (in alphabetical order) appear below.

- [Chris C reviews](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/44952/chris-c?tab=allactions&sort=reviews)
- [emcor reviews](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/48639/emcor?tab=allactions&sort=reviews)
- [Glen_b reviews](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/805/glen-b?tab=allactions&sort=reviews)
- [Scortchi reviews](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/17230/scortchi?tab=allactions&sort=reviews)

Comment: Many thanks for finding this and providing a quick workaround!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apologies for breaking all these URLs.

I've pushed out a change to make these link go to the right place (the links you posted here no longer work).